# Set network adapter priority in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

I have a couple of wireless connections available. I wish to automatically switch to a network connection when my Ethernet cable is plugged or unplugged. If I plug my cable in, it should disconnect my wireless connection. If I unplug my cable, then it connects my wireless. Can I achieve this without any third party software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](http://levynewsnetwork.wordpress.com/2011/12/01/windows-7-default-internet-connection-choice/) shows you where to go.

Under `Network Adapters`>`Advanced Settings...`>`Adapters and Bindings`>`Connections`

click the arrows to set priority.

Comment: Thank you, though I'm not 100% sure if the network messages will always go into the cable. If there are problems with the cable that I do not know, I guess messages will go into the wireless. And this is what I do not expect to happen.